# Is using custom css on bootstrap classes bad habit?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

Let's say I got the following in my index.html and I'm **using Bootstrap**:

```
<head>
bootstrap stylesheet
main.css stylesheet
...


<button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button
```

Btn-primary is a class for making the button blue.

I wanna change all my primary buttons to red for say.

Is it bad I go straight to the Boostrap class or should I make my own? In main.css:

```
btn-primary{ background: red; }
```

*VS*

```
btn-red{ background: red; } //applying that class to the button in question obviously
```

What I'm asking is only about **good practice**.

I know that both work.

I just wanna know if I do use bootstraps' classes for that I'm doing something that's generally not well accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good practice would entail not editing the framework code within the files that are provided by the framework.

In my practice I use an `override.css` file (or section of a file) to specifically override framework styles.

ex:

```
/* Bootstrap.css */
.btn-primary {
    background-color: not-red;
}

/* Override.css - load this after Bootstrap.css */
.btn-primary {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**Note that this is a simplified version, and that sometimes the framework will have more specific selectors than simply a class style, for instance `form .btn-primary` for `<form>` buttons. In this case you may opt to out-specify the framework, or use `!important` on your style.

If Bootstrap updates their framework, it's simple for me to update and keep my styles. This also addresses the issue of redundant classes, as you can still utilise Bootstrap classes with your own styles.

Comment: Don't forget the `dot.` before the class name , also sometimes you should add `!important;` after the property to make sure you've overridden the property with your own value.

Comment: @Ashraf thanks for the correction! I would say use of `!important;` is circumstantial, as you don't always need it unless the framework selectors are more specific than yours. It's definitely worth a mention though :)

Comment: Aaaaand, you said "sometimes" so really you've got it covered!

Comment: I see, so no problem using in my own `override.css` a class with the same name from the framework like in override.css: `.btn-primary{ color:red;}`. Thought that people may not like this :p Thanks a bunch!